# reshaping and filtering data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

My data frame looks like this:

```
Location Data           Value    Value_kind
A        species1        11          single
A        species2        10          mean
A        species3        8           single
A        latitude        5.016
A        longitude       47.716
A        plot            1
B        species1        8           single
B        species2        9           single
B        species3        7           mean
B        latitude        3.203
B        longitude       40.563         
B        plot            2
```

I want to filter only the `single` `value_kinds` and reshape the data it into:

```
Location   species1 species2 species3  latitude  longitude
 A             11      -       8        5.016     47.716
 B              8      9       -        3.203     40.563
```

Comment: And what have you tried? Also, please provide the output of `dput` for your data.

Comment: I used reshape library but I wasn't successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this data:

```
Lines <- "Location Data           Value    Value_kind
A        species1        11          single
A        species2        10          mean
A        species3        8           single
A        latitude        5.016
A        longitude       47.716
A        plot            1
B        species1        8           single
B        species2        9           single
B        species3        7           mean
B        latitude        3.203
B        longitude       40.563         
B        plot            2
"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

try this:

```
library(reshape2)

DF.single <- subset(DF, Value_kind == "single" | Data == "latitude" | Data == "longitude")
dcast(DF.single, Location ~ Data, value.var = "Value")
```

The last line gives:

```
  Location latitude longitude species1 species2 species3
1        A    5.016    47.716       11       NA        8
2        B    3.203    40.563        8        9       NA
```

Comment: Thanks this works great, but now I found that for the same locations I have different plots so that dcast use data length to deal with that. Do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: Its not clear what is wanted regarding `plot`.  Add an example data set and solution at the bottom of question.  Use `dput` on the input data to make it reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your real data looks like your sample data, i.e. rows in each location are in same order and are all present, you can do the following:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(df)

dt[Value_kind == "mean", Value := NA][,
   as.list(setattr(Value, 'names', Data)), by = Location]
#   Location species1 species2 species3 latitude longitude plot
#1:        A       11       NA        8    5.016    47.716    1
#2:        B        8        9       NA    3.203    40.563    2
```

(use `as.character(Data)` if you're using factors instead of strings)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I get an error when I use that for my the origianl data set. Here is the error I get: "j doesn't evaluate to the same number of columns for each group"

Comment: @Nima that's because your data set apparently doesn't have the same data for all "location"'s, e.g. say `species2` is missing for location `D`; if you want to use the `data.table` solution, you'll have to fix your data first